# Performance optimization for Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, linq, performance

I have been working with C# for quite some time but relatively new to the concepts of lambdas and Linq. I was working with a Linq To SQL example and trying to write a generic solution for executing a search against a collection of entities (eg. list of `Customer` objects) where the search parameter will be specified by passing a partially filled object of the entity class itself. I was doing this just to ensure that a person does not have to go on specifying different overloads for different searches based on the entity class attributes and trying to write a generic solution which will cater to any entity class.

Hence I used reflection and an array of predicates to successively apply the Where clauses to the collection.

### Client App

```
using (CustomerManager oCustomerManager = new CustomerManager())
{
   IEnumerable<Customer> customers = oCustomerManager.Load();

   Customer oSearchCustomer = new Customer();
   oSearchCustomer.City = "London";
   oSearchCustomer.ContactName = "Thomas Hardy";

   IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = oCustomerManager.Search(oSearchCustomer);

   foreach (Customer customer in customerList)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(customer.ToString());
   }
}
```

### Manager Class

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Search(Customer searchObject)
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers = DataContext.Customers;
    List<Func<Customer, bool>> result = 

    DataContext.Customers.GenerateFilterClause<Customer>(searchObject);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        customers = customers.Where(item);
    }

    return customers;
 }
```

### Extension Method Utility Class

```
public static class UtilityExtensions
{
   public static List<Func<T, bool>> GenerateFilterClause<T>(this IEnumerable<T> 
          collection, T searchEntity)
   {
        List<Func<T, bool>> whereFilterList = new List<Func<T, bool>>();
        Func<T, bool> predicate = null;

        var propertyList = searchEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in propertyList)
        {
            if (p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().Count() > 0)
            {
               string propName = p.Name;
               var searchVal = 

               searchEntity.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(searchEntity,null);
               if (searchVal != null)
               {
                  predicate = new Func<T, bool>(entity => propertyWhereClause(entity, 
                         searchEntity, propName, searchVal));
                  whereFilterList.Add(predicate);
               }
            }
         }

         return whereFilterList;
     }

      private static bool propertyWhereClause<T>(T obj, T searchEntity, string    propertyName, object searchVal)
     {
           return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, 
                                   null).Equals(searchVal);
      }
  }
```

While the solution is working, I have two specific questions:

- What are the drawbacks of this solution? I was hoping to have inputs regarding performance and cleaner way to rewrite the code.
- Can anyone suggest a more efficient and better solution? That would help me to understand the proper way to utilize the power of lambdas and Linq.

Answer (score 3):

How much did [you look into LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)? Unless you have a reason not to expose the `DataContext`, you can just perform queries on it without using the 'search object'.

```
from c in DataContext.Customers
where c.City == "London" && c.ContactName == "Thomas Hardy"
select c
```

I haven't used LINQ to SQL myself yet, so I can't really tell much about the best practices and whether or not exposing `DataContext` is a good idea. Probably it's best to use an existing ORM framework. [DataObjects.NET](http://dataobjects.net/) looks really nice.

A nice ORM overview can be found on [ORMbattle](http://ormbattle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but there's a lot of code here that doesn't make sense.

### Client app

- You create a `customers` object and never use it. Why?
- You create a temporary `customerList` object only to iterate over it. Why?
- `WriteLine(object)` already calls `ToString` implicitly.

### Manager class and the rest

- You're reinventing the wheel here. This is exactly what LINQ-to-SQL does.